# How to prevent changing of owner name after assigning to other users in crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

If one lead is assigned to other users (eg: XX) , then owner name changes to XX , So how to stop the changing of owner name after assigning.

Comment: are you looking to change queues but not owners?  Assignment means to change owners =/

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at using Queues as your buckets?  That would effectively put it in the XX bucket and the original owner wouldn't change.

Comment: No i dont know about using Queues... how to do that?

Comment: Queues is too large a topic to cover here, but The Hosk has a blog post about it with useful links.  Start there and you'll start gathering the info you need.  https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmbusiness/archive/2012/03/06/crm-2011-queues-could-be-more-useful-than-you-think.aspx#.UWfh35NwpyJ

Comment: The basics about queues is not too large a topic I would say. Each user has a queue and you can route queue enabled entity records to queues while you still have ownership. Leads aren't queue enabled oob so you will need to enable it. Once enabled you can't turn it off, might be good to know.
The reason why the lead disappears from your view "my open leads" is that the view is a filter that takes out all leads that you stand as owner to.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a lead you change owner of it so this is indeed a catch 22. What is it you wanted to happen with the assign? Perhaps there is another way of doing what you expect it to do, share for example

Comment: after assigning , my lead has to be in XX bucket , but owner should be in my name.

Comment: Hi Rickard , how to perform this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want other users able to read or modify the lead without changing the owner you need to share the record, you can decide also the permissions.

You need to click on `Share` or `Sharing` button.

[image]

Comment: yeah k Guido. but i need to assign record , so that the record will deleted from my bucket(My Open leads and will be available in ur bucket.

Answer (score 0):

- You could make use of the Created By field, which does not change when the record is assigned. Filter the view for your bucket based on "Created By".
- If the owner field must not change  you could

  1. Add a custom field called "Worked By" to Lead
  2. Add a custom ribbon button called "Work On" that changes "Worked By" to the current or selected user
  3. then set up views to filter based on the "Worked By" field instead of the "Owner" fiel
  4. "Owner" will remain the same, but "Work On" will change.

Answer (score -1):

I set up a workflow to notify the team when a lead or account owner is changed.

Comment: Can you provide more details?